# continuous booting of PIPO M2

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop

What do I do? My PIPO M2 has been booting continuously for 3 days. I have tried to switch on and off overtime but still not coming up.

Please help me out, I feel like throwing  the pad away.

Kindly treat.

Thank you.

Comment: Give more details on what you did *exactly* for the tablet to end up boot-looping? Were you flashing a ROM onto it? Did something incorrectly? Details please? :)

Comment: Yes, more information is needed. It sounds like it is in a boot loop. If you flashed a custom rom, then you need to wipe the /data and /cache. If you did something else, like delete "system" apps, you may need to reflash a stock rom. And based on your tag, it sounds like you flashed a different ROM.